# c++ wrong values with pragma pack

Tags: c++, struct, pragma, memory-alignment, pack

**header1.h**

```
#pragma pack(4)
```

**header2.h**

```
#include <iostream>

struct my_struct
{
  unsigned int a;
  double b;
};

__forceinline void show_h(my_struct* my_struct_ptr)
{
  std::cout << sizeof(my_struct) << '\t' << my_struct_ptr->b << '\n';
}

void show_cpp(my_struct*);
```

**header2.cpp**

```
#include "header2.h"

void show_cpp(my_struct* my_struct_ptr)
{
  std::cout << sizeof(my_struct) << '\t' << my_struct_ptr->b << '\n';
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "header1.h"
#include "header2.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  my_struct my_struct;
  my_struct.b = 4.56;
  std::cout << sizeof(my_struct) << '\t' << my_struct.b << '\n';
  show_h(&my_struct);
  show_cpp(&my_struct);
  return 0;
}
```

main.cpp, header2.h and header2.cpp sees `my_struct` differently. Seems like it's about `#pragma pack(4)` which is defined in header1.h. Why it's affecting header2.h and main.cpp but not header2.cpp?

**output**

```
12 4.56
12 4.56
16 -9.25596e+061
```

Comment: You've already answered your own question - you need to apply the same `pragma pack` to all modules that share the same headers - so add `#include "header1.h"` to header2.h.

Comment: Why're you not including `header1.h` in `header2.cpp`? It's for such reasons usually the packing is done just above the struct itself instead of having it separate.

Comment: @legends2k no, i don't. those are totally different standalone projects.

Comment: @PaulR header2.h doesn't use header1.h

Comment: Well, either add that or move the packing pragmas to the `struct`.

Comment: It *does* use header1.h if it relies on the `#pragma pack`. Alternatively get rid of the `#pragma pack` entirely (why do you need it anyway ???), or put it somewhere more sensible.

Comment: @PaulR i don't understand. how can header2.h use header1.h since it is including only <iostream>? it would be great if you could tell what's relly going on when i start compiling project.

Comment: @Ivars: All he's saying it that it _should_ ideally be using it, since you're placing related entities in different headers, which is incorrect. So you can edit and make it use it. Or move them all to a single file and be done with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of `header1.h` and do

```
#pragma pack(push, 4)
struct my_struct
{
  unsigned int a;
  double b;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Without this, having the packing done via a separate header will lead to confusions, when it's added in one [TU](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1106149/183120) while not in another TU.

Comment: Welcome. For details on the push and pop, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9x1s805%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).